# Using bearer authorization with Postman nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

*Im fresher to nodejs developer*
 **But there is error in time of Authorization bearer**
*I post some code and screenshot of code*
**Please help me to solve my error**

**router/user.js**
[Here i pass auth middleware, and writen code in middleware/awth.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8adt.png)

```
      router.get('/users', auth, async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.find({})
        res.send(user)
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).send()
    }  
})
```

**middleware/auth.js**
[Here i print token value in terminal but error occure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEX2w.png)

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.header('Authorization')
        console.log(token)        
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

*In postman i login with email and password ,it generate token *

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMifT.png)

**I paste that token in key and value pair in Header **
[In key i written Authorization and in value i written Bearer space token value and send but not prceed any and not shwoing any token value in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weM0l.png)

[Thsis is showing after click send ...error occure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nf0Zm.png)

*and i use latest version of postman 7+
Please help me to solve my error*

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using your Headers tab, use the Authorization tab and select "Bearer Token" from the dropdown, then paste your token into the Token field.

[image: Postman Authorization Token]

In some version of Postman Authorization type 'Bearer Token' doesn't appear, In that case, you can pass a token in a header as below :
[image]

Comment: But can you help me, how i written code in Authorization tab ,pls post what i select from dropdown list type, and what i chage in auth.js file, please please help

Comment: Accept his answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks.

Comment: i paste token in Authorization with "Bearer + token value" and send but not working

Comment: You may need to pass in your Headers as key `Content-Type` value `application/json`. If that doesn't work, it appears you may have something wrong with your Node environment since it was unable to connect. Check your NPM Run settings or however you are running your dev environment.

Comment: Thank You Brother ...Its working... You are great Darren Houston